# MS Access: merging different data from different tables about same set of users into one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am tinkering with an old dataset. It consists of old logfiles of an electronic messageboard of a small club. It has a great nostalgic value for a friend of mine (who was a member of this community), who asked me now to make some sense of it.

Now, I have several tables in my database, which are all some sort of logs (messageboard logins, messages etc). Funny thing is that there seem to be correct dates, but no usernames or user ID-s, but real names and surnames instead. (Many of these are most likely nicknames, but it doesn't matter).

On my friend's request I want to "merge" all logfiles chronologically into one long table, which should eventually give him and his mates an overview of this club's activities.

So I will treat family names and first names together as an user identifier and I have created unified value 'date' for each table (for logins it's a copy of login date, for logouts it's a copy of logout date, for posted messages it's a copy of post date).

Now I would like to put data about users' actions into one table. It should be chronological (sorted by date). Is it possible to achieve it with an MS Access SQL query?

I have tables like these:

```
logins:
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| surname | name |     login_date      |        date         |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Smith   | John | 1997-01-14_18:45:04 | 1997-01-14_18:45:04 |
| Parker  | Mary | 1997-03-15_11:30:45 | 1997-03-15_11:30:45 |
| Smith   | John | 1997-03-20_09:05:24 | 1997-03-20_09:05:24 |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+

logouts:
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| surname | name |     logout_date     |        date         |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Smith   | John | 1997-01-14_19:25:55 | 1997-01-14_19:25:55 |
| Parker  | Mary | 1997-03-15_13:08:01 | 1997-03-15_13:08:01 |
| Smith   | John | 1997-03-20_09:15:58 | 1997-03-20_09:15:58 |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+

posted_messages:
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| surname | name |      post_date      |   post_text   |        date         |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| Parker  | Mary | 1997-03-15_12:30:56 | "Hello world" | 1997-03-15_12:30:56 |
| Smith   | John | 1997-03-20_09:14:01 | "Hello hello" | 1997-03-20_09:14:01 |
+---------+------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

And my desired outcome would be something like:

```
+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|        date         | surname | name |     login_date      |     logout_date     |      post_date      |   post_text   |
+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 1997-01-14_18:45:04 | Smith   | John | 1997-01-14_18:45:04 |                     |                     |               |
| 1997-01-14_19:25:55 | Smith   | John |                     | 1997-01-14_19:25:55 |                     |               |
| 1997-03-15_11:30:45 | Parker  | Mary | 1997-03-15_11:30:45 |                     |                     |               |
| 1997-03-15_12:30:56 | Parker  | Mary |                     |                     | 1997-03-15_12:30:56 | "Hello world" |
| 1997-03-15_13:08:01 | Parker  | Mary |                     | 1997-03-15_13:08:01 |                     |               |
| 1997-03-20_09:05:24 | Smith   | John | 1997-03-20_09:05:24 |                     |                     |               |
| 1997-03-20_09:14:01 | Smith   | John |                     |                     | 1997-03-20_09:14:01 | "Hello hello" |
| 1997-03-20_09:15:58 | Smith   | John |                     | 1997-03-20_09:15:58 |                     |               |
+---------------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `union all`:

```
select date, surname, name, login_date, null as logout_date, null as post_date, null as post_text  
from logins
union all
select date, surname, name, null, logout_date, null, null 
from logouts 
union all
select date, surname, name, null, null, post_date, post_text
from posted_messages;
```

You can either create a new table using `select into`, insert into an existing table using `insert`, or just create a view.